# Website CSS Image position have Bug under Android browser

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on a Website right now.
Pretty easy thing, simple Content one pager.

Now there are two Images of people next to each other like this: 
[image]

But just on Android it shows it like this
[image]

I'm mainly working with CSS there, here's the Code for both Pics and the Body
I'm still working on it and its a little messy and not rightly formatted :)

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color: #fff;
  top:200px;
  height:83%;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #404040;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px
  bottom: 0;      
}

<div style="position: relative; left: 0%; top: 400;">
  <img src="images/bernd.jpg">
</div>

<div style="position: relative; left: 50%; top: 135;">
  <img src="images/witt.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want both of your images in the same row on a desktop and mobile?

Comment: Yes the should be

Comment: Hi! Please check the following link of jsfiddle for the required code. I hope you were expecting the same.
https://jsfiddle.net/g12u1817/8/